# Product of all $n$th-Cyclotomic polynomials less than $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, reference-request, cyclotomic-polynomials

Has the following function been studied? I'm looking for a reference, or an answer displaying some identities and properties
$$
f_m(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{m}\Phi_n(x)
$$

It looks like a factorial analog of cyclotomic polynomials. The degree
$$
\deg(f_n(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)
$$
Something quite interesting I noticed when calculating $f_m(x)$ for low values of $m$ is that all coefficients of terms $x^l$ with $l>\frac{1}{2}\deg(f_n(x))$ are all positive, whilst all coefficients of of terms $x^l$ with $l<\frac{1}{2}\text{degree}(f_n(x))$ are all negative and both are symmetric, but doesn't include the term $x^{\frac{1}{2}\deg(f_n(x))}$. Here's an example
$$
\begin{multline}
\strut f_7(x)
= x^{18} + 2x^{17} + 4x^{16} + 6x^{15} + 8x^{14} 
+ 9x^{13} + 9x^{12} + 7x^{11} + 4x^{10} \\
- 4x^8 - 7x^7 - 9x^6 - 9x^5 
- 8x^4 - 6x^3 - 4x^2 - 2x - 1
\end{multline}
$$
This shows us that
$$
\begin{align} 
f_n(1) &= 0 \\
f_n(-1) &= 0
\end{align}
$$
Here is an [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A076585) for the coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Skew-symmetry of coefficients (True):** We shall take $m \geqslant 2$:

- Exercise $1$: Prove that $\deg f_m$ is even (One way to approach this is to see that $\Phi(k)$ is even for all $k \geqslant 3$. You can see this by pairing up the roots of unity with their inverses. Why does this fail for $k = 1, 2$?)
- Exercise $2$: Prove that the skew-symmetry of $f_m$'s coefficients (the condition that the coefficients in reverse are the negatives of the coefficients in order) is equivalent to the polynomial $g(x) = f_m(x) + x^{\deg f_m}f_m(\tfrac{1}{x})$ being identically zero.
- Exercise $3$: Show that $\Phi_k(0) = 1$ for $k \geqslant 2$ (same idea as Exercise $1$) and $\Phi_1(0) = -1$. Thus, we have $f_m(0) = -1$. Next, show that $f_m$ is monic, so $x^mf(\tfrac{1}{x})$ when evaluated at $0$ is $1$. Deduce that $g(0) = 0$.
- Exercise $4$: Observe that $g$ has more than $\deg f_m$ roots (remember the roots of unity!) and $\deg g \leqslant \deg f_m$. Conclude that $g = 0$ and $f_m$ is skew-symmetric.

**Positivity of first-half (False):** We prove that the second coefficient of $f_{94}$ is $-1$:

- Exercise $1$: Prove that the second coefficient of $\Phi_k(x)$ is $-\mu(k)$ (Hint: Use Möbius inversion)
- Exercise $2$: Prove that the second coefficient of $f_m(x)$ is $-M(m) = -\sum_{k \leqslant m} \mu(k)$
- Exercise $3$: Use a computer to check that $M(94) = 1$.

**Remark:** The value $m = 94$ is the first instance (for $m \geqslant 2$) where $M$ becomes positive. It's good to ponder why this initial value is so large. A computer program shows that this is in fact the first counterexample. The very next value $m = 95$ also has its fourth coefficient being negative. The first counterexample at an odd place (coefficient of an even power of $x$) occurs at $m = 330$.

Comment: Brilliant answer, and good exercises! Thank you!
The last remark regarding $94$ reminds me of how the coefficients of cyclotomic polynomials get greater or equal to $-1, 0, 1$ for $n\geq 105$. Here of course it is because $105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ is the first number that is a product of 3 odd primes... $94$ is quite strange, as it is $2\cdot 47$